# How to prove that $\tan 55^\circ<\pi/2$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How to prove that $\tan 55^\circ<\pi/2$? I checked it on a calculator, but how to prove it though? Is it some trigonometric substitution?

Comment: You can used calculus?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran No I don't know it

Comment: Only the simplest properties such as if h(x)=f(x)-g(x) and h'(x)$\geq$0 for x$\geq$a, then h(x)$\geq$0 for b$\geq$a

Comment: Since $\tan$ is increasing in $(0,\pi/2)$, you can show $\tan 57^o<\pi/2$. Actually this is quite laborious, and involves writing $\frac{\sin(54^o+3^o)}{\cos(54^o+3^o)}$, where you know all values of $\sin 54^o, \cos 54^o, \sin 3^o, \cos 3^o$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the tangent function is convex on $[0,90^\circ)$, you can do this:
\begin{align*}
\tan(55^\circ)
= \tan(\tfrac13\cdot 45^\circ + \tfrac23\cdot 60^\circ)
\le \tfrac13\tan(45^\circ) + \tfrac23\tan(60^\circ)
= \frac{1+2\sqrt3}{3}
< \frac32
< \frac\pi2
\end{align*}
To prove the convexity, the simplest thing would be to calculate the second derivative; if you don't have calculus, you can argue that
$$ \tfrac12\tan a+\tfrac12\tan b
= \tan(\tfrac{a+b}{2}) \cdot \frac{1+\tan^2(\tfrac{a-b}{2})}{1-\tan^2(\tfrac{a+b}{2})\tan^2(\tfrac{a-b}{2})}
\ge \tan(\tfrac{a+b}{2}) $$
when $\tan(\frac{a+b}{2})\ge 0$.  (The trigonometric identity comes from the usual identities for $\tan(u\pm v)$ with $u,v=\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2}$ and a bit of algebra; the inequality comes from the fact that $\frac{1+x}{1-c^2x}$ is an increasing function of $x$ and $\tan^2(\frac{a-b}{2})\ge 0$.)  Then the convexity for weights other than $\frac12,\frac12$ follows by continuity.

Comment: (Fixed the elementary proof of convexity, as it had a simple algebra error in it.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant on AsdrubalBeltran's answer, starting from the equation

$$-2+\sqrt{3}=\tan(165^\circ)=\tan(3\cdot55^\circ)=\frac{3\tan(55^\circ)-\tan^3(55^\circ)}{1-3\tan^2(55^\circ)}$$

This implies that $\tan(55^\circ)$ is a root of the cubic polynomial

$$P(t)=t^3+(6-3\sqrt3)t^2-3t+(\sqrt3-2)$$

Note that

$$P(0)=\sqrt3-2\lt0$$

and

$$P(-1)=-1+(6-3\sqrt3)+3+(\sqrt3-2)=6-2\sqrt3\gt0$$

These inequalities imply $P$ has two negative roots and one positive root.  It suffices therefore to note that

$$P(3/2)={1\over8}\left(27+18(6-3\sqrt3)-36+8(\sqrt3-2) \right)={1\over8}(83-46\sqrt3)\gt0$$

to conclude that

$$\tan(55^\circ)\lt{3\over2}\lt{\pi\over2}$$

In fact, if you're willing to do a little arithmetic, it's possible to show $P(\sqrt2)\lt0$ and $P(10/7)\gt0$, so that

$$1.41421\approx\sqrt2\lt\tan(55^\circ)\lt{10\over7}\approx1.42857$$

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

Note that : $\tan(3\cdot x)=\frac{3\tan(x)-\tan^3(x)}{1-3\tan^2(x)}$

Then $$-2+\sqrt{3}=\tan(165^\circ)=\tan(3\cdot55^\circ)=\frac{3\tan(55^\circ)-\tan^3(55^\circ)}{1-3\tan^2(55^\circ)}$$
Now  how:

$$-\frac{18}{73}=\tan(3\cdot\tan^{-1}(1.5))=\frac{3\cdot1.5-(1.5)^3}{1-3(1.5)^2}$$

but it is known that $\tan{3x}$ is  increasign, if $$-2+\sqrt{3}<-\frac{18}{73}\Longrightarrow 55^\circ<\tan^{-1}(1.5)\Longrightarrow \tan{55^\circ}<1.5\Longrightarrow \tan{55^\circ}<\frac{\pi}{2} $$